# How to filter and remove Maps in Lists based on multiple conditions in Dart

Tags: dart

I have a List containing a Map with two fields:

```
    [
      { 'temperature': 36.1, 'date': 2020-10-27 10:49:48.173099 }, 
      { 'temperature': 37.1, 'date': 2020-10-27 10:48:10.079658 },
      { 'temperature': 36.3, 'date': 2020-10-26 10:48:00.000 },
      { 'temperature': 37.1, 'date': 2020-10-25 10:49:00.000 },
      { 'temperature': 36.1, 'date': 2020-10-25 15:49:00.000 },
      { 'temperature': 38.0, 'date': 2020-10-24 11:49:00.000 }
    ]
```

The datatype temperature is a double and the date is a DateTime object.

The goal if have is to have a List in the end which only contains the Maps with the highest temperature on a date (time doesn't matter). So, in the end there should only be max one day left. The result of the above list would then be:

```
    [
      { 'temperature': 37.1, 'date': 2020-10-27 10:48:10.079658 },
      { 'temperature': 36.3, 'date': 2020-10-26 10:48:00.000 },
      { 'temperature': 37.1, 'date': 2020-10-25 10:49:00.000 },
      { 'temperature': 38.0, 'date': 2020-10-24 11:49:00.000 }
    ]
```

I used the .where() and contains(), but get stucked on how to filter the date and remove items from the List.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd collect the highest temperatures per date and build a new list from those.

```dart
DateTime dateOf(DateTime timestamp) => 
    DateTime.utc(timestamp.year, timestamp.month, timestamp.day);

List<Map<String, dynamic>> bestTemperaturePerDate(List<Map<String, dynamic>> original) {
  var best = <DateTime, Map<String, dynamic>>{};
  for (var map in original) {
    var date = dateOf(map["date"] as DateTime);
    var bestSoFar = best[date];
    if (bestSoFar == null) {
      best[date] = map;
    } else {
      var temp = map["temperature"] as double;
      var bestTemp = bestSoFar["temperature"] as double;
      if (temp > bestTemp) {
        best[date] = map;
      }
    }
  }
  return [...best.values];
}
```

Updating the list in-place is probably possible, but much more complicated because while iterating the elements, you have to remove or change earlier element when you find a higher temperature for the same date. You have to be careful to avoid quadratic behavior.
Maybe something like:

```dart
DateTime dateOf(DateTime timestamp) => 
    DateTime.utc(timestamp.year, timestamp.month, timestamp.day);

void retainBestTemperaturePerDate(List<Map<String, dynamic>> original) {
  var indexForDate = <DateTime, int>{};
  var cursor = 0;
  while (cursor < original.length) {
    var map = original[cursor];
    var date = dateOf(map["date"] as DateTime);
    var index = indexForDate[date];
    if (index == null) {
      // This is a new date. Keep it here.
      indexForDate[date] = cursor;
      cursor++;
      continue;
    }
    // There is already an element before cursor for the same date.
    var temp = map["temperature"] as double;
    var existingTemp = original[index]["temperature"] as double;
    if (temp > existingTemp) original[index] = map;
    // Remove element at cursor by moving the last element into its place. 
    // This is a constant time operation, where `removeAt(cursor)` is linear.
    var last = original.removeLast();
    if (cursor < original.length) {
      original[cursor] = last;
    } else {
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

This doesn't preserve the ordering of the list elements, but it avoids removing elements in the middle of the list.